# What's the name of the program that tells you how many packages need to be updated?

Tags: synaptic

what's the name of the program that tells you how many packages need to be updated when you log in? I have it on some machines but not on others.

For example, it will say (from memory):

10 packages need updating
5 security patches

etc.

Answer (score 7):

For text mode logins the file `/etc/motd` ("message of the day") is displayed after login. This file is created at startup based on the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/`.

The message about available updates is created by `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available` which just calls  `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean `update-manager` or `synaptic`.